# Cant read number char frequency

Tags: c, arrays, char, frequency

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fb;
    char data[255];
    int c=0;
    int count[75] = {0};
    fb = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    fgets(data, 255, fb);

    /* Start finding frequency*/
    while (data[c] != '\0')
    {
        if( data[c] >= '0' && data[c] <= 'z')
        count[data[c] - 'a']++;

        c++;
    }    
    for (c = 0; c < 75; c++)
    {
        /** Printing only those characters
            whose count is at least 1 */

        if (count[c] != 0)
            printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'a',count[c]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example input file: "Fred Fish 12345678"

I am able to handle space from the input file, but the program does not read Frequency of capital letter as well as number character. What can I change in the program help fixing the problem. After reading the freq, my plan is to save the file so that I can compress using HUffman

Comment: What motivated you to settle on the constant 75?

Comment: Maybe `- 'a'` should be `- '0'`

Comment: You need to count the characters based on the input. That's not what you do (your code is also not safe). Also please lookup to the ASCII table. If you only check between `0` and `z`, you're excluding a space character and including symbols like `:`,  `;` , ect ... A huffman algorithm doesn't take account if a character is between 0 - z. If the character isn't present, add it to the array.

Comment: @Bathsheba I'm trying to follow ASCII, the range '0' to 'z' is the range 48 to 122, a range of 75 characters.

Comment: @KarelG The input will only contain alphabetical character and an array of 10 numbers

Comment: @AnhMinhTran: Don't do it like that. Write portable code instead which will probably wind up tidier anyway. That is, don't assume ASCII *encoding* and base something around the literal "0...9A..Za...z".

Comment: @AnhMinhTran Don't forget that there are non alphanumeric characters between `9` and `A`, and `Z` and `a` ...

Comment: @KarelG: Absolutely. In EBCDIC it's worse still.

Comment: @Bathsheba you must live in the past 

Comment: No, I just like to write portable C. There's a whole plethora of functions to help you; `isalpha`, `tolower`, `toupper`, &c. Note the standard insists that 0-9 are always consecutive, but pretty much anything else goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fb;
    char data[255];
    int c = 0;
    int count[75] = { 0 };
    fb = fopen("Input.txt", "r");
    fgets(data, 255, fb);

    /* Start finding frequency*/
    while (data[c] != '\0')
    {
        if (data[c] >= 'a' && data[c] <= 'z') // here you check normal letters
            count[data[c] - 'a']++;
        else if (data[c] >= 'A' && data[c] <= 'Z')
            count[data[c] - 'A' + 26]++; // Capital letters will be stored after lower cases
        else if (data[c] >= '0' && data[c] <= '9')
            count[data[c] - '0' + 51]++; // Numbers will be stored after capital letters
        c++;
    }

    // count[] is initialized as following : 
    // From count[0] to count[25] == Occurence of low case characters
    // From count[26] to count[51] == Occurence of capital characters
    // From count[52] to count[61] == Occurence of numbers from 0 to 9

    for (c = 0; c < 61; c++)
    {
        /** Printing only those characters
        whose count is at least 1 */
        if (count[c] != 0) {
            if (c < 26)
                printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c + 'a', count[c]); 

                // Starting from 'a', iterating until 'z'
            else if (c < 52)
                printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c + 'A' - 26, count[c]);

                // Same as for low case characters
                // Substracting 26 because we already have iterated through the first 26 low case characters
                // Starting from 'A' until 'Z'

            else if (c >= 52)
                printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n", c + '0' - 51, count[c]);

                // Same as for characters
                // Substracting 51 because we already have iterated through low cases and capital characters
                // Starting from '0' until '9'
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that, considering the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you were storing the capital letters and numbers in a negative indice of your array `count`by substracting `'a'`which is equal to `97`in ASCII. This should work but I couldn't test it yet so be careful with it.

For the printing, we do the same thing for low case characters, then capital characters and then numbers : we start from the first one : `'a'`, then `'A'`, then `'0'`, iterate until the last one using c and printing them all. We use the fact that in C, `'a' + 1 = 'b'`, `'A' + 1 = 'B'` etc.

For the input `Fred Fish 12345678` the output with this code is :

```
d occurs 1 times in the entered string.
e occurs 1 times in the entered string.
h occurs 1 times in the entered string.
i occurs 1 times in the entered string.
r occurs 1 times in the entered string.
s occurs 1 times in the entered string.
F occurs 2 times in the entered string.
1 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
2 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
3 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
4 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
5 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
6 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
7 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
8 occurs 1 times in the entered string.
```

Comment: Forgot to change the `printf`, fixing it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this counts characters that does not appear in the input for some reasons. There are also counted characters that the console cannot present so it show it as ? with a square. What do you think can be a reason for this

Comment: @AnhMinhTran I forgot to change the printing. Now it should work just fine. Does it ?

Comment: can you explain to me how it works? The program still cant read capital letter though, and "0,1,9" cant be read. Can you explain to me the logic of the 2 lower "count" code below?

Comment: @AnhMinhTran I tried to comment and explain what I did. Is it more clear ? 
Also, I added my output with the exact same code. Yours is different ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess chaning the code

`count[data[c] - 'a']++;`

to

`count[data[c] - '0']++;`

if data[c] is less than 75, then count[data[c] - 'a'] does not work

Comment: Chaging to what you suggest would change the output of the program to count once for each letter from a - j though some is not in the input

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the `'a'` to `'0'` in your code to take all capital letters and numerics into account.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

       ...
    /* snippet */
       ...    

    while (data[c] != '\0')
    {   
        if( data[c] >= '0' && data[c] <= 'z')
        count[data[c] - '0']++;
        c++;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    }   

    for (c = 0; c < 75; c++)
    {   
        /** Printing only those characters
         whose count is at least 1 */

        if (count[c] != 0)
            printf("%c occurs %d times in the entered string.\n",c+'0',count[c]);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```